# Background image in Html template

Tags: html, css

I bought a template and I want to set background image I put in code in each HTML file. But  as soon as I publish the website on local host background image disappears.

I would like to how can I set background image on each page.

Comment: Dear Avani Di ! SO is not for such things. You google around and look for solutions. And after you have tried and still found any error. Paste your code and your query. We can try to help you our dear. But first give it a try yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to se this css: (In case you want to add background Image through CSS)

```
.selectorName {
  background-image: url(image.file);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Hi ! With respect I would like to say that, OP's question is not clear. It lacks information. We cannot assume, OP has to use CSS property in CSS file. Why not the `<img src=""/>` tag. Also, why not creating an image using Javascript :) 

That's why I commented OP to add details as per SO guidelines !